# Access to MessageResources

Tags: java, localization, resources, resourcebundle

What's the analogous of

```
Resources.getMessage(request,"key");
```

(it's in `org.apache.struts.validator` package)?

I need to take the right string according to the language in use and put that string in an array.
These strings have a variable part. For example:

```
The field %s is required
```

I want to take the `The field` and `is required` from the MessageResources

**EDIT**

I've used

```
ResourceBundle myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageResources");
String msg = MessageFormat.format(myResources.getString("errors.required"),
                                new Object[] { title });
```

It works, but only with the default language

Comment: The answer is in the question tags: ResourceBundle. Have you read its javadoc? BTW, there is no `Resources.getMessage()` in the servlet API.

Comment: You're right. It's in the `org.apache.struts.validator` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resource bundle for this in idiomatic Java. The bundles are properties files, and they are named according to their locale's.

Here is a link to ResourceBundle in the Java API documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: I already use the Message class (in the struts framework) that references a resource bundle. In a servlet I use Resources.getMessage(request,"key"). In a java class, I think I can use ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyResources"), but if the message has a variable part, how could I do? Have I to use two different key in MyResources?

Comment: @JB Nizet: Thank you. I've used `MessageFormat.format(myResources.getString("errors.required"),new Object[] { title });`. If you put the comment in an answer, I'll accept it.